# How to read a log file in windows that will be rolled over?

Tags: java, logging, nio

In Linux when you open an input stream of a file, another process can rename that file. So when a file is rolled over, you still can read from the stream. In Windows, when you open an input stream, that file cannot be renamed until the input stream is closed. How can I read a file without affecting the 'rename' process?

I have tried using java.nio.FileChannel. It works for reading and writing at the same time to a file by different process (E.g Java process reads and notepad writes), but not for renaming a file (E.g. Java process reads but the rename command does not work).

Comment: I'm running a risk of seeming flippant when I say this, but you might consider not using Windows for your production deployments. Honestly, this is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Sometimes one doesnt have that choice. And java is Run-anywhere, right? Better to program in OS-dependent functionality, if easy to do, imho.

Comment: You might also consider not reading from files that are being written concurrently, which is basically a 'code smell', but using a database, which gives you all the required properties.

Comment: I have an idea of doing this. After you have read the newly appended lines close the reader, this way the other process trying to do a rotation will succeed. But the process doing log rotation has to try several times, until it sees no other process is reading from it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest of solutions would be the following (I am just copying from one of my comments)

After you have read the newly appended lines close the reader, this way the other process trying to do a rotation will succeed. But the process doing log rotation has to try several times, until it sees no other process is reading from it.

The [apache commons IO Tailer](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io//apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) can do this.